# On my database, I got an attribute that has a lot of diferent values separeted with comma. E.G: Attribute "sintomas" - value "Outros,tosse"

Tags: python, pandas, database, knn

I got a project on my college that we have to take an database an make some data analasys on it.
My problem is that the database has one attribute that have a lot of different datas on in, separeted with comma.

I have to do the KNN algorithym on it and I'm changing all the qualitative values to numbers, but I dont know what to do on the situation showed below. I was thinking on getting all the substrings and adding as attribute, for example, in the row 0 i got "Outros, Tosse", so i would have an attribute "Outros" and another "Tosse", and if the substring is present, the value would be "1" and if its not, the value would be "0". I'm using colab with pandas right now. Someone knows what can i do in this situation?

Data sample:

```
    sintomas                             profissionalsaude 

0   Outros, Tosse                               2
1   Febre, Tosse, Distúrbios Gustativos         1
```

.
.
.

Thanks!

Comment: Just one thing that I wanted to recommend, seeing that you're new on StackOverflow... when you post your sample data/code, you should try to post it as text instead of a picture. It makes it much easier to work with

Comment: It's fine, no need to edit now, just keep in mind for the next time

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
pd.get_dummies(
    df['sintomas'].str.split(', ').explode()
).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

The idea is to first `split` strings by `,`, then `explode` it into a column with repeating indexes (with index representing the original index = row number), then `get_dummies` to do one-hot encoding, `groupby` that index and `sum`

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': ['a,b,  c', 'b, c', 'a']})

pd.get_dummies(
    df['feature'].str.split(',\s*').explode()
).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  0  1  1
2  1  0  0
```

Comment: This kinda worked pretty well! I mean, it actually did what i meant, but i saw another problem, that is from the datas from my database. The code splited all the data that was separeted by (', '), but it saw that has some values that after the comma there's no space in it (','). Do you know what can I do? By the way, thank you for your time and the answer!

Comment: Sure, you can use regular expressions in `split`, so `.split(',\s*')` is gonna split based on a comma followed by zero or more spaces (so it will work when there is no space, 1 space, ..., N spaces, ...) -- see my updated example

Comment: I'm sorry, im knew to the plataform i didnt see that was more comment below, i saw it now and put the (',*) and it worked! Thank you! You saved my project

Comment: Btw i already upvoted it, but as I'm new, my reputation is low so it dont change on the page :(
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"